# Order-independent Deep Learning

Tags: neural-networks

I have a dataset with parallel time series. The column 'A' depends on columns 'B' and 'C'. The order (and the number) of dependent columns can change. For example:

```
            A   B    C
2022-07-23  1  10  100
2022-07-24  2  20  200
2022-07-25  3  30  300
```

How should I transform this data, or how should I build the model so the order of columns 'B' and 'C' ('A', 'B', 'C' vs 'A', C', 'B'`) doesn't change the result? I know about GCN, but I don't know how to implement it. Maybe there are other ways to achieve it. Thank you!

Comment: In Graph Neural Networks order-dependency is removed by spectral analysis (eigenvector decomposition). Perhaps you could reformulate the problem as a directed graph with rows directed toward future and columns bidirectional.

Comment: @mantrid I have used a transformer model that is also order independent.